# Having an issue with a switch statement inside a loop

Tags: c++

So this code is just something I've been messing with, but I cant seem to get it to work right. The switch statement wont continue looping after it finishes its first case. I'm just trying to make it change letters in words essentially. I'm not quite sure, how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

This keeps telling me I need more words so I am just randomly writing, please don't mind these words, they are just placeholders to make the system less angry at me for summarizing my issue into three sentences.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ans;
    char fileName[50];
    string inp;
    int length;
    ifstream inpFile;
    ofstream outFile("output.txt");

    do{

        cout << "";

        cin.getline(fileName, 50);
        inpFile.open(fileName);

        if(!inpFile.is_open()){
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }   

        string word;
        char enc;
        char temp;

        length = word.length();
        char * cstr = new char [length + 1];
        strcpy(cstr, word.c_str());

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){

                    switch(cstr[i]){

                    case 'A':{
                        temp = cstr[i];
                        temp = '0';

                        enc = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                    case 'a':{
                        temp = cstr[i];
                        temp = '1';

                        enc = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            cout << "test1";

        }

        cout << "Test2";

        delete[] cstr;

    }while(ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y');
    cout << "Test3";

}
```

Comment: What's the input?

Comment: This is the exact input: Words Backwards Forwards Reverse Words Backwards Forwards Reverse Words Backwards Forwards Reverse Words Backwards Forwards Reverse Words Backwards Forwards Reverse Words Backwards Forwards Reverse Words Backwards Forwards

Comment: nevermind, doesn't matter. read your warnings. You will be mad at yourself. :)

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I'm grateful for the help, but that makes no sense to my pea brain.

Comment: When your compile, how do you make it from a cpp file into something that will execute? (or What compiler are you using?)

Comment: I've been using Dev-C++ to compile and run.

Comment: You tagged this question with c++ but I see cstrings and c functions. Why don't you use the easier c++ functions

Comment: Probably because I know no easier way. I'm not very well versed in C++. So I've just been doing it with the little I do know.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that one. It appears to be gcc based, in which case you may need to add "--Wall" to the command line to get warnings. MOST compilers will tell you right out if you do something they can see is obviously problematic. Here's the relevant setting for gcc https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: Is there a compiler you would recommend instead? I use Dev-C++ because it was something I had used in the past.

Comment: @NoahPersons Dev C++ is an IDE, not a compiler. You may configure it to use a different than the default toolchain as delivered with it.

Comment: I recommend you read the warnings. I recommend you use the debugging tools. I don't care which compiler you use as long as you do that. You don't even read anything in this code, from the file you open.

Comment: Recommendation: Write less code before testing it. You catch bugs faster that way and don't allow them to gang up on you. The time cost of finding bugs is not linear. It's often exponential. 1 bug takes one bug-hunting unit of time. 2 bugs often takes many more than just 2 units of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open the the file, but you never read anything from it. Your variable word will always be empty, so the length will be 0.